# Problem understanding merge of sorted linked lists in python

Tags: python, sorting, data-structures, merge

I have the code below that merges two sorted linked lists in python.
what I can't understand is that at what point it adds the value of the second list to the first list.
I would be grateful if somebody could explain this to me.

```
def merge_sorted(self, llist):
    # set p and q pointers to head nodes of list1 and list2 (both of p,q are objects of class Node)
    p = self.head
    q = llist.head
    s = None

    # if either of the two lists doesn't exist return out of function (no point of sorting)
    if not p:
         return
    if not q:
         return

    # if both head pointers exist:
    if p and q:
        #based on which header data being smaller set s to that one
        if p.data <= q.data:
            s = p
            p = s.next # move p to next element, can also write : p = p.next
        else:
            s = q
            q = s.next # move p to next element, can also write : q = q.next

        new_head = s

        # go through all elements of both lists (after p/q being updated)
        while p and q:
            if p.data <= q.data:
                # the p/q here is one item iterated ahead of when we set s = p/q
                s.next = p
                # then we move s one item ahead, it its next pointer
                s = p  # could also write s = s.next
                p = s.next # could also write p.next, we move p one item ahead

            else:
                s.next = q
                s = q # could also write s = s.next
                q = s.next # could also write p.next, we move p one item ahead

    # when you reach the end of the list in one of the lists, set s to whatever is left of the other list and finish merging   
        if not p:
            s.next = q

        if not q:
            s.next = p

        self.head = new_head
```

Comment: `s.next = ` is where the merge occurs, and `self.head = new_head` where the complete replacement of the head could be the original head or a new head if `llist.head` came before the original `self.head`

Comment: @PeterWood Thank you :)

Comment: There's no need for the `if p and q`. You already exit the method if either one is null. Also, check your comment on the line `q = s.next`. You probably want to change `p` to `q` in the comment. Finally, your "merge" doesn't include the second list if the first list is empty. If `self.head` is null but `llist.head` is non-null, shouldn't `self.head` be set to `llist.head`?

Comment: @JimMischel, yes you are right about the first one being empty part, I will fix that in my code, thanks :)